# "System.Numeric.Vectors" error when I send int with 4 digits

Tags: c#, web-services, assembly, servicestack

I'm making a web service with ServiceStack, between its libraries he use System.Numeri.Vectors. I have a rare problem, the WS's request has a property int? (int nullable), everything works perfect until I send a value with 4 digits in said property (only with 4 digits run the error).

Code:

Request's definition

```
    [DataMember]
    public int? PaymentTypeId { get; set; }
```

Request in postman

```
"paymentTypeId": 2231
```

Error

```
"message": "No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado."
```

PD: The error only happens if in paymentTypeId entered a 4-digit value, with 3 or 5 digits does not give error

Comment: It sounds like a glitch loading System.Numerics.Vectors; and... this particular package is *hugely* problematic between frameworks - MS screwed up the assembly forwarding table in net46* in particular. You could try adding an explicit package reference to System.Numerics.Vectors in your application, and/or adding assembly binding redirects, but... if you're on net46* and libs use netstandard, this one is ... pain. Also: IIRC the transitive dependency tree loader in `dotnet restore` gets it wrong too, for a double-whammy of pain.

Comment: <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net461" /> 
do you mean this reference?

Comment: yeah, that's the one; but *as a transitive dependency* from libs that target netstandard when running on net46*: it gets ... messy; due to problems in the bindings. Frankly, just one more reason to avoid net46*